# Why my list reload after my pop up finished?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I have a list which contains images.I put a method every image which is open popup 
( I mean I use  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" in manifest.xml`) and when I click my image my new activity opens. For now evething works fine.

**My first activity :** I use this : `setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

**On my popup activity :** I use this: `setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

When I click image and open popup , yes the screen rotate and become **lanscape** and when I back button my screen rotate again and but **the problem is :** when I back my main activity and when roate again to portrait the list is reload again, I do not know why it is?

And is it possible to I do not want to rotate my first screen with the popup activity?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is reloading because the activity is destroyed and re-created when the orientation changes.  The simplest thing is to manually handle orientation changes in the activity - and do nothing about it.  Also, you can specify the portrait or landscape for an activity in the Manifest.  Your manifest would then contain something like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".PreviewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
    </activity>

    ...
</application>
```

Note the lines `android:configChanges` in the declaration of each activity.  Also note the lines `android:screenOrientation` - with these lines added you don't need to call `setRequestedOrientation` in the code.